# Como forzar un array a realizar un IndexOutOfBoundsExcepcion para probar que funciona catch?

Tags: java, array, excepciones, try-catch

Estoy tratando de realizar un ejercicio sobre try y catch como puedo forzar el array para que por pantalla me muestre `IndexOutOfBoundException`?

**Adjunto codigo:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Array de 5 elementos
        int [] numeros= new int[5];
        numeros(numeros);
        //Array IndexOutOfBoundException
        int [] numerosOutOfBound= new int[5];
        numeros(numerosOutOfBound);
        //Array vacio
        int [] vacio = null;
        numeros(vacio);
    }

    public static void numeros(int [] numeros) {

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;

        try {
            for(i = 0;i<numeros.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("Ingresa un numero:");
                numeros[i]=lector.nextInt();
            }
        }

        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e2) {
            System.out.println("No debe sobrepasar la capacidad del array");
            for(i = 0;i<numeros.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(numeros[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException  e) {
            System.out.println("El array no esta creado");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: numeros[9999999]=lector.nextInt();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando este código para cuestiones de prueba, simplemente agrega a la longitud del bucle +1 de esta forma no encontrara el elemento a insertar dentro del array `numeros` y se provocará un error **[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** :

```
     for(i = 0;i<numeros.length + 1;i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingresa un numero:");
            numeros[i]=lector.nextInt();
        }
```

**Recuerda que el error a "atrapar" debe ser [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** ya que estas realizando operaciones en un array.

---

En realidad [**IndexOutOfBoundsException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) es la superclase de **[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** y podrías usarla pero [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) esta especificada para usarse cuando el índice es negativo o mayor o igual que el tamaño de la matriz (array).

> **[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** Lanzado para indicar que se ha accedido a una matriz con un índice ilegal. El índice es negativo o
>   mayor o igual que el tamaño de la matriz.
>
> [**IndexOutOfBoundsException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) Se arroja para indicar que un índice de
>   algún tipo (como una matriz, una cadena o un vector) está fuera de
>   rango. Las aplicaciones pueden subclasificar esta clase para indicar
>   excepciones similares.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Justo necesitaba eso! he creado otro metodo en mi actividad para probar este error :)

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre los dos tipos de errores? El de ArrayIndexOutBoundsException y el IndexOutBoundsException ?

Comment: Agregué una respuesta más especifica, @azucarilla saludos.